# Green Card for Indian spouse

Tags: usa, greencard, indian-citizens

I am a 70 years US Citizen and my wife is a 65 years Indian Citizen.  I frequently visit India.  Can I petition I-130 for my  wife  -(along with G-325A for me and my wife) while I am in India and can I give my Indian Address in I-130. I will stay in India until this process is over.  Can I send form I-130 to Chicago?  What about I-485 and I-864?  When are these forms required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can file the petition while you are in India, but you have to intend to re-establish domicile in the US concurrently with, or before, your wife enters the US.

Yes, a standalone I-130 filed from outside the US goes to the Chicago Lockbox.

Your wife will go through Consular Processing in India. I-485 is for applying for Adjustment of Status in the US, which is not what your wife is going through; it is not used in this process. I-864 Affidavit of Support will be asked of you during the process.